# Make Apache server available on a LAN via custom ServerName

Tags: apache, localhost, apache-config

is it possible to set up an Apache server on a machine which is part of a LAN, then allow machines on the LAN to access the server via a custom ServerName (instead of Localhost). I want to serve a simple website in an office space using a short ServerName (no ports etc if possible), but I want to make sure this is possible (after originally being certain it was!). THanks in advance.

Comment: I think this one should be on superusers http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to setup DNS or something similar so that the name will resolve to the server, but that is it.

You might want to ask this on ServerFault though as it will get you better, more detailed answers.